# Oracle Function -- I am passing a date in an Oracle function. Before I use that date in Sql queries

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a function I want to pass a date. beDate is what i am passing.

I want to update beDate as last day of beDate month if beDate is Last_business_day otherwise last_day of previous month.

Can someone lease provide the syntactically correct answer for the IF part in the below code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function AnyFunction ( beDate IN varchar2 )
   RETURN date
IS

IF beDate = [ Last_Business_Day ] then beDate = last_day(beDate) ;

ELSIF beDate >  [ Last_Business_Day ] then beDate = last_day(beDate) ;

ELSE beDate = last_day(add_months(last_day(beDate),-1) ) ;

END IF ;

BEGIN 

END;
```

Comment: `[ Last_Business_Day ]` is invalid PL/SQL (or SQL), please show us your real code

Answer (score 4):

Correct `IF-ELSE` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function AnyFunction ( beDate IN date )
   RETURN date
IS
   r_date DATE;
BEGIN
  IF beDate >= [ Last_Business_Day ] then  rDate = last_day(beDate);
  ELSE rDate = last_day(add_months(last_day(beDate),-1) ) ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN r_date;
END;
```

Date should be passed as `DATE` type. Using `VARCHAR2` would create conversion problems.

---

In my opinion there is no need for function or IF at all. `CASE` expression could do the same.

```
SELECT t.*
   CASE WHEN beDate >= [ Last_Business_Day ] THEN  last_day(beDate)
        ELSE last_day(add_months(last_day(beDate),-1) )
   END AS last_date
FROM tab_name t;
```

Comment: beDate  must be IN OUT to be an assignment target.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I've added local variable to handle it

Comment: Firstly I Do not want To Return  r_date , Rather I want to Use it in My other SQL Queries .
Can ANyone Frame the logic for calculating --> [ Last_Business_Day ] as well . last business date means ,, date of last Friday ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (beDate in date)
  2    return date
  3  is
  4    l_last_business_day date;
  5    retval date;
  6  begin
  7    -- Calculate last working day in the beDate's month. In Croatian calendar,
  8    -- ordinal numbers of Saturday and Sunday are 6 and 7 - change it if necessary.
  9    -- I'm intentionally not using "Saturday" (nor Sunday) as our language word for
 10    -- it is "subota", Germans call it "Samstag", etc. - it is probably simpler to use
 11    -- numbers than words.
 12    -- Inline view is here to create the whole month; in it, I'm searching for the
 13    -- MAX date which doesn't belong to weekend (i.e. days 6 and 7)
 14    select max(datum)
 15      into l_last_business_day
 16      from (select trunc(beDate, 'mm') + level - 1 datum
 17            from dual
 18            connect by level <= to_number(to_char(last_day(beDate), 'dd'))
 19           )
 20      where to_char(datum, 'd') not in (6, 7);
 21
 22    -- What to return?
 23    if beDate >= l_last_business_day then
 24       retval := last_day(beDate);
 25    else
 26      retval := last_day(add_months(beDate, -1));
 27    end if;
 28
 29    -- TRUNC so that the time component (hours, minutes, seconds) aren't returned
 30    return trunc(retval);
 31  end;
 32  /

Function created.

SQL> select
  2    f_test(date '2018-04-30') lbd_april,
  3    f_test(date '2018-04-15') not_lbd_april
  4  from dual;

LBD_APRIL           NOT_LBD_APRIL
------------------- -------------------
30.04.2018 00:00:00 31.03.2018 00:00:00

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: Include example for DEC 2017]**

29.12.2017 was Friday, and it was the last working day in December. Therefore, function should return 31.12.2017 as a result and - guess what? - it does:

```
SQL> SELECT f_test (DATE '2017-12-29') lbd_dec
  2    FROM DUAL;

LBD_DEC
-------------------
31.12.2017 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Or, with your SELECT statement:

```
SQL> select f_test (to_date('29-DEC-2017','DD-MON-YYYY')) from dual;

F_TEST(TO_DATE('29-
-------------------
31.12.2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: '2018-04-27' is not the Last Business day , so why it is returning 30th April :) 
I think requirements are mis-understood in the above logic .. Last business day == last working day .
If last working day is Monday then it will be Last business day 
Example 30-MAR-2018 , 29-DEC-2017 , 30-APR-2018 are last business day

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misunderstood what you were saying. I've modified the code (basically, instead of `= 5` it should be `not in (6, 7)`), have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks For Framing code , but Still their is an issue with it --> 29-DEC-2017 is returning 30-NOV-2017 rather it should return 31-DEC-2017 becuase 29-DEC-2017 is last business day .

Comment: I've just checked it (and edited my message by adding the 29.12.2017 as a parameter) - function returns 31.12.2017, as expected. I don't know how you managed to return 30.11.2017 ...

Comment: select f_test (to_date('29-DEC-2017','DD-MON-YYYY')) from dual

Please try above Query .

Comment: Works just fine; I've posted the output at the bottom of my answer, have a look. Did you run the current function code, the one that is now posted in my message? Or is it the previous, *wrong* one?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function AnyFunction ( beDate date )
    RETURN date
IS
   r_date DATE;
BEGIN
  IF beDate >= next_day(last_day(beDate)-7,'FRIDAY') then  
      r_Date = last_day(beDate);
  ELSE 
      r_Date = last_day(add_months(last_day(beDate),-1) ) ;
  END IF;
  RETURN r_date;
END;
```